# Mysql search query with join and subqueries

Tags: mysql, rdbms, database

I have a large Mysql database connected with a php platform.

I have few table with this structure:

Table USER:

```
id (int auto increment not null, primary key)
name (varchar 200)
spoken_lang (varchar 400) /* The value of this field is the id of the table languages, 
                             with the char ';' like a separator ;*/
```

Table LANGUAGES

```
id (int auto increment not null, primary key) /* Used also in the prev table */
name (varchar 200)
```

Is it possible to make a single search query that is be able to compare the column user.name, and also the table languages.name?

Something like this:

```
SELECT user.name, languages.name as lang 
FROM 
user JOIN languages ON user.spoken_lang = ......
```

Comment: I noticed you have a CSV column or multivalue column. This breaks the rules of relational databases and I would rather fix that then trying to develop this query. Storing 10;12;12 in a column in a SQL database is a bad design rather use a NoSQL solution for that.

Comment: Just so it's clear - the spoken_lang fields look like 1;2;3;4?

Comment: @dethtron5000 yes, is like that

Comment: @Namphibian do you think that it's possible modify the scheme of the DB to fix this problem and to have a better design solution?

Comment: @Danilo yeah very possible. However the question is not if it is possible but how much work is involved. If you have lots of queries reports and procedures in production this can be a substantial change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first have to recommend you normalize your table -- you shouldn't be storing a list of results in a single column.  If possible, consider creating a `User_Language` table which stores the `User_Id` and the `Language_Id`.

However, you can achieve the same results using `FIND_IN_SET` and `REPLACE`:

```
select u.name, l.name language
from user u
  join languages l on find_in_set(l.id, replace(u.spoken_lang,';',','))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311df/3)

Comment: I can replace all the ';' with ',' directly on the DB, this is not a problem. Are the performance of the queries significantly better if I normalize my schema than the use of find in set?

Comment: @Danilo -- Generally speaking, normalizing your database is considered best practice.  Does that mean it will produce the best performance -- not necessarily -- it just depends.  I would imagine in your particular case, yes, it would produce a better performance as it would be able to utilize appropriate table indices.

Comment: In the table User I have the same case with another column. Considering that this column with the separator could assume from 0 to 500 values and I actually have 4000 users...if I create the table for normalize my schema, in the worst case i have to work with a table formed by 2.000.000 (2 million) of rows!!!!!! Are you sure that the performance is really improved with normalization?????

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `like` as the `join` condition:

```
select u.name, l.name as lang
from user u join
     languages l
     on concat(';', u.spoken_lang, ';') like concat('%;', l.name, ';%')
```

The idea is to add the separator (`';'`) to the beginning and end of each language.  And then search for cases where the spoken language is like the language.  For instance, if you have `'English;Spanish;Russian'`, then it will compare as:

```
';English;Spanish;Russian;' like '%;Russian;%'
```

And find a match.  You don't have to worry about partial matches, because the semicolons delimit each language.

In MySQL, you can also do this with `find_in_set()`, but that requires replacing the semicolons with commas:

```
on find_in_set(l.lang, replace(u.spoken_lang, ';', ',')
```